# Drupal 7 - View listing Organic Groups AND content within that group

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups

I'm trying to create a view that lists all of my Organic Groups on a page AND lists the content within that group. Specifically, I would like to show image fields that have been posted to each group.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? I can't seem to get the relationships right.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing in Drupal 6. Trying to use a Block in Views. I know a Relationship will have to be set up associating the content type of the content associated with the Group.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view that listas all content (filter by your choice), make sure you include the field **Content: Audience group** (og_group_ref).

Then you can go to Format > Format > Settings (style_options) and group by that field.